# Kubernetes: creating pod with specific environments

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I tried to create a pod with a particular environment for uwsgi configuration , but it was this message : 
*failed to load "phptime.yml": JSON: I can not unpack the number in the value of the string type Go*
when I tried to run this command : 
**kubectl create -f phptime.yml** 
I found that trouble in environments that has names like this: 
**UWSGI_HTTP-MODIFIER1** 
**or 

UWSGI_PHP-SAPI-NAME** 
or 
**UWSGI_MASTER-AS-ROOT** 
but with environments that has a next names all ok: 
**UWSGI_HTTP** 
or 
**UWSGI_INCLUDE** 
A lot of our containers took configuration from environments and I need include all of my conf environments. This is my rc conf:

> ```
>   containers:
>   - name: phptime
>     image: ownregistry/phpweb:0.5
>     env:
>     - name: UWSGI_UID
>       value: go
>     - name: UWSGI_GID
>       value: go
>     - name: UWSGI_INCLUDE
>       value: /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/test/test-dev0/.uwsgi_dev.ini
>     - name: UWSGI_PHP-SAPI-NAME
>       value: apache
>     - name: UWSGI_HTTP
>       value: :8086
>     - name: UWSGI_HTTP-MODIFIER1
>       value: 14
>     - name: UWSGI_PIDFILE
>       value: '/tmp/uwsgi.pid'
>     - name: UWSGI_MASTER-FIFO
>       value: '/tmp/fifo0'
>     - name: UWSGI_MASTER-AS-ROOT
>       value: 'true'
>     - name: UWSGI_MASTER
>       value: 'true'
>     ports:
>     - containerPort: 8086
>     resources:
>       limits:
>         cpu: 500m
>         memory: 200Mi
>       requests:
>         cpu: 500m
>         memory: 200Mi
>     volumeMounts:
>     - mountPath: /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/test/test-dev0/
>       name: site
>       readOnly: true
>   volumes:
>   - hostPath:
>       path: /home/user/www/
>     name: site
> ```

Is this kubernetes issue or it`s my? How to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Try to single-quote `UWSGI_HTTP-MODIFIER1` variable -- `value: '14'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must quote all of the values that you want to set as environment variables that the yaml parser might interpret as a non-string type.

For example, in [influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/gce/coreos/kube-manifests/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb/influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml) the values `true` and `false` are quoted because they could be interpreted as booleans. The same constraint applies to purely numerical values.

Comment: But if I need environments like a UWGI_HTTP-MODIFIER1 where "_" and "-" together I can't configure my applications?

Comment: Is it the *name* that you are having trouble with rather than the *value*?